# How to start Lambda edge viewer request locally?

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to start aws cloudfront lambda edge functions locally and mock the event to see the response from one of the four function.

I have made some changes in viewerRequest function of lambdaEdge, is there some way possible to test it locally?

I have tried serveless-offline, I'm able to start localhost but not able to hit any request to it.

I tried using postman put/post request by sending event in request body but it always gives 404

Answer (score 0):

On this page [Lambda@Edge event structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html), you can find the event structure for viewer request event.
[image]

Use this JSON, modify it as per your need, and invoke the lambda function from the AWS console. Just paste the event JSON in below text-area.

[image]

Comment: if the changes are are at local and server is started at localHost then aws console would not work right?